# django view for password_reset_confirm.html

Tags: python, django, reset-password

I am trying to implement a reset password feature in a Django Project.

I did almost everything:

- User enters his email
- email is sent with a link
- User goes to the link, and type new password and confirms it

This is where I stopped.

This is the form I am using in password_reset_confirm.html:

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.new_password1.errors }}
<p class="aligned wide"><label for="id_new_password1">{% trans 'New password:' %}</label>{{     form.new_password1 }}</p>
{{ form.new_password2.errors }}
<p class="aligned wide"><label for="id_new_password2">{% trans 'Confirm password:' %}</label>{{     form.new_password2 }}</p>
<p><input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Change my password' %}" /></p>
</form>
```

Where should this form submit? what should I write in action="?"? Does Django have a view for this? or should I write one myself?

Comment: This functionality is included in Django already. See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views).

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I know. I am trying to do that. But documentation does not say anything about the view part. This form should be submitted somewhere right?

Comment: But the [view part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm) is exactly what that page talks about! That's what's done for you. It even tells you what URL name to use, which is exactly the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `action` attribute should be empty so that the form is sent to the current URL.

This is the common pattern for form handling in Django: a URL displays a form on a `GET` request and processes it on a `POST` request.